# Why original_transaction_id is changed when ios subscription renewing in sandbox environment?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

Per this [doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/Chapters/ReceiptFields.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010573-CH106-SW12)

> original_transaction_id
>
> This value is the **same** for all receipts that have been generated for a specific subscription. This value is useful for relating together multiple iOS 6 style transaction receipts for the same individual customer’s subscription.

Recently, I find the **original_transaction_id** is changed when subscription renewing in sandbox environment, which is same as **transaction_id**. However, only the **original_transaction_id** was same, the transaction_id was changed when subscription renewing several months ago.

Here is one subscription with 3 auto_renew receipts

```
 { quantity: '1',
   product_id: 'com....',
   transaction_id: '1000000476973577',
   original_transaction_id: '1000000476973577',
   purchase_date: '2018-11-23 05:47:39 Etc/GMT',
   purchase_date_pst: '2018-11-22 21:47:39 America/Los_Angeles',
   original_purchase_date: '2018-11-23 05:47:07 Etc/GMT',
   original_purchase_date_pst: '2018-11-22 21:47:07 America/Los_Angeles',
   expires_date: '2018-11-23 05:50:39 Etc/GMT',
   expires_date_pst: '2018-11-22 21:50:39 America/Los_Angeles',
   web_order_line_item_id: '1000000041449251',
   is_trial_period: 'false',
   is_in_intro_offer_period: 'false' },
 { quantity: '1',
   product_id: 'com....',
   transaction_id: '1000000476974277',
   original_transaction_id: '1000000476974277',
   purchase_date: '2018-11-23 05:50:39 Etc/GMT',
   purchase_date_pst: '2018-11-22 21:50:39 America/Los_Angeles',
   original_purchase_date: '2018-11-23 05:49:44 Etc/GMT',
   original_purchase_date_pst: '2018-11-22 21:49:44 America/Los_Angeles',
   expires_date: '2018-11-23 05:53:39 Etc/GMT',
   expires_date_pst: '2018-11-22 21:53:39 America/Los_Angeles',
   web_order_line_item_id: '1000000041449274',
   is_trial_period: 'false',
   is_in_intro_offer_period: 'false' },
 { quantity: '1',
   product_id: 'com....',
   transaction_id: '1000000476975015',
   original_transaction_id: '1000000476975015',
   purchase_date: '2018-11-23 05:53:39 Etc/GMT',
   purchase_date_pst: '2018-11-22 21:53:39 America/Los_Angeles',
   original_purchase_date: '2018-11-23 05:52:48 Etc/GMT',
   original_purchase_date_pst: '2018-11-22 21:52:48 America/Los_Angeles',
   expires_date: '2018-11-23 05:56:39 Etc/GMT',
   expires_date_pst: '2018-11-22 21:56:39 America/Los_Angeles',
   web_order_line_item_id: '1000000041449309',
   is_trial_period: 'false',
   is_in_intro_offer_period: 'false' }
```

The original_transaction_id and transaction_id are same in the above three receipts.

Was the ios subscription behavior changed? or is there a bug in sandbox environment?

Comment: I have the same issue with SOME of my test devices. Some of them receive receipts where each `original_transaction_id` is unique and apple server notifications send different one for those subscriptions.